# Prisma self relation to display related posts

Tags: prisma

I am trying to create a prisma schema for a self relation. I would like to be able to show related posts for each post. Here is my post model:

```
model Post {
  id                 Int  @id @default(autoincrement())
  title              String
  content            String
  relatedPosts       Post[]
}
```

I am unsure on how to get this to work, the error message I am getting says that I need to define the other side of the relationship.

Comment: In case helpful, here's my answer to a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74567283/239712

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to create a [many-to-many self relation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/self-relations#many-to-many-self-relations). In such cases, you need to create two fields:

1. One field to represent the suggested posts for a given parent post (named `relatedPosts` in the example)
2. One field to represent the parent for a given suggested post (named `relatedPostParent` in the example)

This is what the syntax will look like

```
model Post {
  id                Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  title             String
  content           String
  relatedPosts      Post[] @relation("RelatedPosts", references: [id])   // child post (post that are suggested)
  relatedPostParent Post[] @relation("RelatedPosts", references: [id])   // parent post (parent post of a suggested post)
}
```

Note that this is an [implicit](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/many-to-many-relations#implicit-many-to-many-relations) many-to-many relation. The [article linked at the top](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/self-relations#many-to-many-self-relations) also shows how to create an [explicit](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/many-to-many-relations#explicit-many-to-many-relations) many-to-many relation, if that is what you'd prefer.